# Forced return error for a successful request

Tags: javascript, error-handling, axios

Could I return error for a successful request to debugging app by Axios

I have config

```js
import axios from 'axios';


const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_PREFIX,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});
```

And request

```js
...
updateQuestionnaire(args) {
  return instance.put('/questionnaireResponse', args);
},
```

I want return error with specific code (XXX), but have nothing

```js
...
updateQuestionnaire(args) {
  return instance
    .put('/questionnaireResponse', args)
    .then(data => new Promise((res, rej) => {
      rej(new Error({status: 401}))
    }))
},
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: [Error constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) does not take an object as argument

Comment: @HMR Thank you! Hmm, maybe I can use like this `.then(data => Promise.rej(data))`

Comment: You could reject simply by `.then(data =>Promise.reject(anyValue)` where `anyValue` could be anything so you could reject with an object containing status 401: `.then(data =>Promise.reject({status:401})`

Comment: it feels like it's a backend problem. the server is not responding the right http code. If you have the backend code, you should change it there. Else try @HMR code. I thinks its'c in the right direction.

Comment: @HMR Sysix Thank you